# The IE doesn't show address bar for popup

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, window.open

I am on the parent page from which I use javascript in jsp, to open a popup and I used the method window.open("url","windowName"," width,height,locastionx, locationy") to get a popup. Everything works fine in all browsers(like Mozilla, Chrome etc) except that the Popup doesn't show the url or address bar in Internet Explorer 10.

I am attaching the screenshots for reference

The following screenshot is a popup from IE

[image: IE10]

The following is a screenshot of popup from Mozilla

[image: Mozilla]

Is there a way in which the window.open method which will show address bar in the IE?

Thanks for helping

I did read in few online blogs that the behaviour of the popup is different with the IE7 or above than in the Mozilla or the Chrome browsers.

Comment: People normally ask how to hide it in those other browsers.

Comment: Yes, but it is different in my case. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been busting my head around this problem a couple of days, I've browsed a lot of sites to find the answer, finally I discovered that IE when you run your code in a local environment it hides the URL bar, but when I run it in a Test/Prod server the address is shown (not showing the URL address is clearly a security flaw), this just happens only in IE, which is annoying, for FireFox and Chrome work as intended, and it's kind of a headache if you need to test because it may seem like an error or bug.

Here are the links that should make the things clearer:

**Complete cross-browser window.open() documentation** -> [here](http://www.gtalbot.org/BugzillaSection/Bug195867GDR_WindowOpen.html)

**MSDN open method notes** ->
[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(VS.85).aspx)

**Server Fault question about IE trust policies related to the URL bar** -> [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/366620/disable-address-bar-in-internet-explorer-9)

Comment: Have you got any reference links? You can improve you anwer by adding them, I think they will prove useful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll edit my answer with the required information.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Cam Pat